# Is there a way to find the range and domain of a cubic spline?

Tags: geometry, spline, bezier-curve

Wolfram alpha is telling me there isn't.   I guess this reduces down to finding the inflection point in some way and testing against points A and D.

Here's the equation I'm using.
$$
x=(1-t)^3*A_{x}+3*((1-t)^2)*t*B_{x}+3*(1-t)*(t^2)*C_{x}+(t^3)*D_{x}
$$
$$
y=(1-t)^3*A_{y}+3*((1-t)^2)*t*B_{y}+3*(1-t)*(t^2)*C_{y}+(t^3)*D_{y}
$$

Comment: I presume first terms in your formulas are $(1-t)^3$, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain" here? The above functions are defined for any value of $t$.

Comment: @Aretino DOH. Also Re Domains:  Splines are defined for t=[0:1]

Comment: If so, why are you asking for the domain?

Comment: Because the curve can exit the rectangle made by the endpoints.

Comment: The [0,1] portion of the cubic polynomial will exist inside the rectangle defined by the xmin/xmax and ymin/ymax of the control points. In fact, it will lie inside the convex hull of the control points.